# Whose bodies were taken out of Walter's house?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In a few episodes of Breaking Bad's season 2, the preface shows two bodies being taken out of Walter's house. Who were those two people as I do not recall anyone being murdered at Walt's place?

Comment: You're going to need to give us a lot more details, specifically in which of the series' 62 episodes this happens.

Comment: This only happens in season 2, AFAIK. I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sorry if you didn't watch season 2 all the way through, but well, you did ask...

The 2 bodies removed from the premises in body bags were **victims from the airplane collision** that happens in [the season 2 finale](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/ABQ). The B&W flashbacks intentionally didn't reveal it, to keep it a mystery. The teddy bear in the pool also fell from the plane. Walt's actions indirectly led to this collision.

Comment: P.S. This keeps happening, so I had to comment: Editors, please don't convert the answer to a spoiler. I don't think there's a point in *hiding an entire answer* (in fact, I'll rephrase it now). On M&TV, some answers will just inevitably spoil things.

Comment: It seems a stretch to assume Walt's actions caused the crash. Her father (the flight control guy) would maybe have also been distraught enough if she was only revealed to be on drugs (again), as he seems very concerned with his daughter's wellbeing.